# Can I post article on blog.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, blog

Just came across blog.stackoverflow.com. Can I as regular user post articles on this site? If yes, I did not see any login on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot post there. The blog is reserved for posts by Stack Overflow employees about Stack Overflow.